# Feynman physics relativistic mass

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, inertial-frames, collision

[image]

Here is the page I read from Feynman physics. My question is when we ride along in a car moving with horizontal speed of the particle one then we get situation in fig 16-3a, according to last section of this chapter, the vertical speed in rest reference frame is equal the vertical speed in moving reference times $\sqrt{1-(v_x/c)^2}$, $v_x$ is moving speed, so the vertical speed of particle 2 in rest reference frame is $u\tan(\alpha)\cdot \sqrt{1-(v_x/c)^2}$,is that true?

If it is, then $w\sqrt{1-(v_x/c)^2}$ is equal $u\tan(\alpha)\cdot \sqrt{1-(v_x/c)^2}$ in the rest reference frame, however, from fig16-3b, $u\tan(\alpha)$ is equal $w\sqrt{1-(u/c)^2}$, then I plug everything in the
$$w\sqrt{1-(v_x/c)^2} = u\tan(\alpha)\cdot\sqrt{1-(vx/c)^2}$$
in rest reference frame, but both side not equal. I expect to be equal because both vertical speed should be equal in the rest frame under this condition. So where I got wrong? Many thanks.